# Read JSON file - asp.net (where to put - controller / view)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, getjson

I am building a project is asp.net , and Im reading 2 JSON files that I create from a queries.

The loading of the json file is not working. He shows me an error while he trying to read it.

I think its because the controller and the location of the queries.

**This is the controller:**

```
  public ActionResult TotalPs()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "TotalPs";
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult allParking()
    {
        var totalQueryParkingLot =
              from lot in db.parkingLots
              orderby lot.PricePerHour
              select lot;

        return Json(totalQueryParkingLot);
    }
```

**And this is the part of the view:**

```
    @{
      ViewBag.Title = "TotalPs";
     }

    $(document).ready(function () {
    var url2 = "@Url.Action("allParking","parkingLots")";
    initialize();
    $.getJSON(url2, function (data2) {
        $.each(data2, function (i, field) {
            createMarker(data2);
```

**UPDATE**
http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=mrwmygmntmjz.png

http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=ynyzmltjiafg.png

http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=nzyyt42k3jit.png

**Please Help Me**

Comment: The critical part of the question is the "it doesn't work" part. That could mean a virtually infinite number of things. Can you narrow it down?

Comment: Ive added 3 pictures. please take a look. Tnx!!

Comment: and finally, try not to mix the scripts in the View. it's not a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "view" you are referring to should be in the Scripts folder.

and then in the view that you want the scripts to render, you do:

in the RegisterBundles of the BundleConfig.cs, you add the scripts into a bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bundledScripts").Include(
            "~/Scripts/scriptOne.js"));

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bundledScripts")
```

Update:

1. the BundleConfig.cs can be found in the App_Start folder (see 1st pic)
2. add the following code:

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bundledScripts").Include(
            "~/Scripts/scriptOne.js"));

3. in the page where you want the scripts to take into effect, put this code:

   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bundledScripts")

Watch out for the names in bundle and render. They have to match. 
Hope it helps you.

Comment: Please do not add the snippet part for c#/Razor code. It does not make any kind of sense and it won't work. It's only there for standard HTML/CSS/JS

Comment: I'm sorry for the snippet part Camilo. I am new to this interface. I was not familiar with what to use exactly.

Comment: Please someone . I didnt understand

Comment: Tell us your project structure. Better if you can show picture of it.

Comment: http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=mrwmygmntmjz.png                                                      http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=ynyzmltjiafg.png                                                             http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=nzyyt42k3jit.png

Comment: Ive added 3 pictures. The first one is the error Ive see when Im trying to read the json result.